# Magento 1.9 Admin Panel is showing Blank...Header with no menus

Tags: magento-1.9, database-schema

Magento admin panel is showing blank with header with no menus

[image]

Comment: please check var/log and share error that you are getting

Comment: We disabled the logs in Magento Admin Panel....So it is not showing any logs in BackEnd....

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try.

1. View the page source for evidence of the error.
2. Use browser dev tools to check for console errors, e.g. of a JavaScript error, failed AJAX call, etc.
3. Check the webserver (Apache/NGINX/etc.) error log.
4. Enable the Magento logs in
           the database by finding the row in `core_config_data` with the
           path "dev/log/active " and setting the value to 1.